# How do I use ASP.NET Login Controls when my Login.aspx is not at the root of my application?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm using the [ASP.NET Login Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx) and [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx) for membership/credentials for an ASP.NET web application.  It keeps redirecting to a Login.aspx page at the root of my application that does not exist.  My login page is within a folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the LoginUrl property for the forms item?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="1440" ></forms>
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at [CoderSource.net](http://www.codersource.net/asp_net_forms_authentication.aspx).  I had to put the correct path into my web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        ...
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/FolderName/Login.aspx" />
        </authentication>
        ...
    </system.web>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: I guess that by default Microsoft assumes you'll have a Login.aspx page at the root: http://domain.com/Login.aspx.  You have to change the web.config to override that default assumption.

Comment: The default value of the `loginUrl` property is indeed `"~/Login.aspx"`.