# How do I filter nodes of TreeView and Menu controls with sitemap data sources based on user permissions?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, sitemap

I'm using the [ASP.NET Login Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx) and [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx) for membership/credentials for an ASP.NET web application.  And I'm using a [site map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx) for site navigation.

I have ASP.NET TreeView and Menu navigation controls populated using a SiteMapDataSource.  But off-limits administrator-only pages are visible to non-administrator users.

---

> **[Kevin Pang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1574/kevin-pang)** wrote:
>
> I'm not sure how this question is any
>   different than your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263/how-do-i-best-handle-role-based-permissions-using-forms-authentication-on-my-as)…

The other question deals with assigning and maintaining permissions.

This question just deals with presentation of navigation.  Specifically TreeView and Menu controls with sitemap data sources.

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" />
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="False" />
```

---

> **[Nicholas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2808/nicholas)** wrote:
>
> add role="SomeRole" in the sitemap

Does that only handle the display issue?  Or are such page permissions enforced?

Answer (score 1):

I had to set securityTrimmingEnabled to "true" in my web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web>
        ...
        <siteMap defaultProvider="default">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="default"
                    type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider"
                    siteMapFile="web.sitemap"
                    securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
            </providers>
        </siteMap>
        ...
    </system.web>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this question is any different than your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263/how-do-i-best-handle-role-based-permissions-using-forms-authentication-on-my-as), but I'll try to answer it anyways.

If you want a tutorial on how to implement role-based authentication, check out the one from [4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616112800/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082703-1.2.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

securityTrimmingEnabled="true" works for internal pages that have a config file restricting permissions, you can also add role="SomeRole" in the sitemap to ovveride the display mechanism, which is useful if you have menu items to external sites.